# When should I vote to delete a question on Web Applications?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-questions, votes

On Meta Stack Exchange Robert Cartaino's answer to [When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/289691) gives general guidelines about when we should vote to delete a question.

During the 7 years of Web Applications there were changes in its scope and nowadays some questions are off-topic and become closed on the last 2-3 years. Should we vote to delete those questions because they are now off-topic and have less than 0 points?

Example:

Qs tagged [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) that are closed and score -1 or less: [[webapp-rec] closed:1 votes:-1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwebapp-rec%5D+closed%3A1+votes%3A..-1).

Comment: Two new criteria to add, I think: creation date and number of views. Example: Questions created on 2010 with less than 101 views and less than 0 points should be deleted
[\[webapp-rec\] views:...100 votes:..-1 created:2010](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwebapp-rec%5D+views%3A...100+votes%3A..-1+created%3A2010)

Comment: Those question could not be automatically deleted by Roomba because they have an answer with +1, I think( reference [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/289691) to [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/289691) )

Comment: @pnuts I just vote on the resultss of the previous query. At least 2 questions were deleted after my vote :)

Answer (score 3):

There is some guidance at [Help Center > Privileges > access to moderator tools](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> **When should I delete questions?**
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be
>   flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good
>   answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator
>   attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great
>   answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; they
>   can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another
>   question.
>
> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the
>   number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the
>   question and all its answers.
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can
>   vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users when
>   a post scores -3 or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted
>   despite having lots of votes or for being new, please flag it for
>   community moderator attention.
>
> You can view a list of posts with outstanding delete votes via the
>   moderator tools delete tab.

Though IMO neither of the two categories picked out above ("any good answers" and "closed as duplicates") really applies for the tag ([webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec)) you have chosen for your example - one that is appropriate because off topic now by definition but nevertheless very popular.

The same place though offers a link to a different, and possibly clearer, post about the Deletion process:

> See also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a definite "Yes" - these should be deleted, a.s.a.p. (regardless of their score and of any As). While in some cases there may be some reason to retain a closed Q those tagged [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) (and others that should be) are a 'special' and clear-cut case. SE has a site dedicated to software recommendations that has appropriate and specific guidance for how to ask such questions and has more chance of showing up-to-date information than WA can hope to, since these Qs here are Closed, so no answers may be added.

As long as such examples remain on WA there is a risk they will attract yet more such off-topic (now) Qs here. The quality (spelling, punctuation, grammar, layout etc) at initial posting of those that end up here with that tag is also probably worse than average in general, so requires additional 'housekeeping effort' when this is already in limited supply and, again, sets a bad example until edited suitably.

Comment: I think that some [tag:webapp-rec] questions should not be deleted, like [\[webapp-rec\] views:10k is:question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwebapp-rec%5d%20views%3a10k%20is%3aquestion) (557 questions). I'm wondering if the "historical lock" should be applied to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

SE sites delete some questions automatically by a bot called Roomba, so don't waste your delete votes on questions that already meet the automatic deletion criteria. For details see [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/289691) to [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/289691)

Besides looking at [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) use other criteria like old questions with very low number of views. Just review them carefully, they could be "hidden gems" that for some reason they could be found by other means like using a "strange wording".

Example:

[[webapp-rec] views:...100 votes:..-1 created:2010](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwebapp-rec%5D+views%3A...100+votes%3A..-1+created%3A2010)  for Questions created in 2010 with less than 101 views and score less than 0:

- [Anyone know of an online notebook app which syncs or works with Symbian? [closed]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/anyone-know-of-an-online-notebook-app-which-syncs-or-works-with-symbian)
- [Web documents that can be edited from iPhone [closed]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/web-documents-that-can-be-edited-from-iphone)